# Sorting exams dividing the task between m teachers

Tags: sorting

I have to find 2 efficient ways to sort 1000 exams according to the students' last names and give the complexity. The task has to be divided between m teachers.
I think one efficient way is to give each teacher a range of letters, for example one teacher has to sort the exams with the last names from A to D, the other one from E to H and so on, using any efficient sorting algorithm like quick sort. Then I concatenate all the ranges because they are already sorted. For the complexity I thought: I suppose each teacher has 1000/m exams to sort, so each one sorts in (1000/m)log(1000/m), in total that is m*(1000/m)log(1000/m), that is 1000*log(1000/m). Is this correct?

I don't know how to do the other way. I though about doing multiple passes of radix sort, one for each teacher. But they would have to do this in turns, first one teacher has to sort according to the last letter, then other one would have to sort again according to the before last letter and so on. In the first way everyone sorts at the same time but that does not happen using radix sort, I don't know if that makes it less efficient though.
If you can think of a more efficient way of doing this I would be thankful.

Comment: You can randomly assign each teacher the exams, let each teacher sort in their own time, then merge in linear time.

Comment: But isn't that similar to the first way? Maybe you are right but I thought I would have to think of something different

Comment: Maybe the alternative is radix sort as you described.

Comment: Can you compare names in constant time? What does it mean that the task *has* to be divided among $m$ teachers, *formally*?

Comment: Yes, I can compare them in constant time. They didn't give me any more details. Why do you ask for a formal definition? Do you think there is more than one way to interpret that?

Comment: I think we can assume constant time comparison, since student names don't typically involve more than a few words.